# my SVG drawing animation works on codepen, but it doesn't work on my website with sprite.svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to make an svg drawing animation, and I actually done one in codepen (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RyvmRm), but on my website the animation doesn't want to work. On my website I use sprite.svg. Maybe mouseover doesn't work because of sprite? I don't really know. Thanks for your help. And I changed my icon a little so path length differ from the codepen.

```
<symbol id="person1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 578.43 551.6" style="enable-background:new 0 0 578.43 551.6;" xml:space="preserve">
        <defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:15px;}</style></defs>
        <path stroke-dasharray="946" class="cls-1" d="M280.79,314.56a150.83,150.83,0,0,0,150.8-150.8c0-83.27-67.54-150.35-150.8-150.35S130,81,130,163.76,197.52,314.56,280.79,314.56Z" transform="translate(7.5 -5.91)">
            <animate begin="person1.mouseover" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="946; 0" dur="1s" calcMode="linear"></animate>
        </path>
        <path stroke-dasharray="1365" class="cls-1" d="M19.89,550H543.54a19.75,19.75,0,0,0,19.89-19.9c0-104.08-84.65-189.19-189.2-189.19h-185C85.12,340.93,0,425.58,0,530.12A19.75,19.75,0,0,0,19.89,550Z" transform="translate(7.5 -5.91)">
            <animate begin="person1.click" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="1365; 0" dur="1s" calcMode="linear"></animate>
        </path>
</symbol>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say you use sprite.svg? How are sprites included?

Comment: I mean I put all my icons in one file and in html I do <svg><use xlink:href="image/catalog/sprite.svg#person2"></use></svg>

Answer (score 0):

This works out to be a bit awkward becaus of incomplete browser implementations.

First, let's look at the issue that raises from what the spec has to say. Your animation references `begin="person1.mouseover"`. `person1` is the symbol element itself. [SVG 2 says](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/struct.html#UseAnimations) that to animate only the referencing use element and not all instances where the icon is referenced, you must use the form `begin="mouseover"`, without identifying an element. That is currently only implemented by Firefox.

Instead, you have to place the `<animate>` element on each `<use>` element. That works, in principle, because what you are animating is a CSS property (`stroke-dashoffset`), that is inherited by the shadow DOM and the contained paths. Only problem: the path lenghts differ, but you can only set one animation value.

There is a solution to that, also: The [`pathLength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength) attribute. You can set an artifical `pathLength="1000"` for both paths, and the `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` will be recomputed as if that was true.

That is the moment where Safari is left behind, because it does not implement that attribute.

The second set of compatibility problems arises when Firefox references an external file: using a `<style>` element no longer works. You must place the styles inline on the `<symbol>` element and let them be inherited by the paths.

So, here is one variant that at least works in Firefox and Chrome (Edge/IE do not implement SMIL animations). To demontrate, the sprite svg is placed inline, but if you follow this pattern, it also works with an external file.

Note the `pointer-events:visible`, it makes reacting to the mouseover a bit more predictable.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
    <symbol id="person2" viewBox="0 0 578.43 551.6"
            style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:15px;stroke-dasharray:1000;pointer-events:visible;">
        <path id="p1" pathLength="1000" d="M280.79,314.56a150.83,150.83,0,0,0,150.8-150.8c0-83.27-67.54-150.35-150.8-150.35S130,81,130,163.76,197.52,314.56,280.79,314.56Z" transform="translate(7.5 -5.91)" />
        <path id="p2" pathLength="1000" d="M19.89,550H543.54a19.75,19.75,0,0,0,19.89-19.9c0-104.08-84.65-189.19-189.2-189.19h-185C85.12,340.93,0,425.58,0,530.12A19.75,19.75,0,0,0,19.89,550Z" transform="translate(7.5 -5.91)" />
    </symbol>
</svg>

<svg width="100" height="100"><use xlink:href="#person2">
    <animate begin="mouseover" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
             values="1000; 0" dur="1.5s" calcMode="linear"></animate>
</use></svg>
<span>or</span>
<svg width="100" height="100"><use xlink:href="#person2">
    <animate begin="mouseover" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
             values="1000; 0" dur="1.5s" calcMode="linear"></animate>
</use></svg>
```

Comment: That's a lot of info! Thank you so much :)